# Conditional Formatting based on Active Cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting of excel. My requirement is `using conditional formatting` i want to highlight cells $A$1:$D$4 if the selected cell is between $A$1:$D$4. If the selected cell is outside $A$1:$D$4 then it should not get highlighted. One of the way is to write formula in conditional formatting

```
IF(....)
```

such that it should return true if the selected cell intersects with the given range($A$1:$D$4) or else it should return false. But what shall be the formula i require that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat round about strategy:

1. Define a Name, lets say `rActive` and set it to refer to a constant `=FALSE`
2. Conditional Format the required range using a formula `=rActive`
3. Add a worksheet select change event


   `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

       ThisWorkbook.Names("rActive").RefersTo = _

           Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, [A1:D4]) Is Nothing

   End Sub`

The result:  the range is conditionally formatted based on the value of the name `rActive`.
`rActive` is updated by the event each time you change the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks chris. But I don't want to use any VBA code. Is there any method through which without using VBA code and just directly the formulas i can achieve this.

Comment: I can find no workable solution without using VBA.  I did get close using the old XL4 macro command `GET.CELL` but I could not get it to update on selection change, only by forcing a sheet recalc.